# Display Array Value in Header (H1) Tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql, header

I would like to use employee name in h1 tag. Can anyone please tell us how to do this. See the comment description for further info.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Employee Name is _______ </h1> //I want to display employee name here
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('config.php');
$qry = "SELECT * FROM emp_data where eName='dinesh'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="edb-table">';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>Name:</td><td><a href='emp_name.php?name=" . $row['emName'] . "'>".$row['emName'] . "</a></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td>".$row['emDOB'] . "</a></td></tr>"; 
        echo "<tr><td>Department:</td><td>".$row['emDepart'] . " </td></tr>";
    } 
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a loop of your employees, so do you want multiple h1 elements or just one as the standard convention is to have one h1 element on a page?

Comment: you have the name there static in you query anyhow? but otherwise do as Dagon says, move the php above the html, save name in variable and result rows in string that you echo in the table then

Comment: may i know where your array variable get from ? for example, you can do  <h1>Employee Name is <?php echo $arrayName[0];?></h1> for first index value in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Dagon suggested this would be:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include('config.php');
$table_content = "";
$employee_name = "";
$qry = "SELECT * FROM emp_data where eName='dinesh'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $employee_name = $row['emName'];
    $table_content .= "<tr><td>Name:</td><td><a href='emp_name.php?name=" . $row['emName'] . "'>".$row['emName'] . "</a></td></tr>";
    $table_content .= "<tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td>".$row['emDOB'] . "</a></td></tr>"; 
    $table_content .= "<tr><td>Department:</td><td>".$row['emDepart'] . " </td></tr>";
}
mysql_close();

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Employee Data</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Employee Name is <?php echo $employee_name; ?></h1>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ddb-table">
      <?php echo $table_content; ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: although you do not need a while loop if you just expect one result, you could also add `LIMIT 1` to your query to make sure you have only 1 result

Comment: Thank you folks.. I am new to php and It works.. Also I would like to tell my special thanks to hexerei software.. :)